# Textarea max-width got no respect

Tags: css, forms, layout, textarea, width

The [textarea in this codepen](https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/XVQooJ) and the code below overflows in slim viewports. It has `max-width: 100%` from [`.preset-box`](https://unpkg.com/@plangrid/structure@0.34.0/main.css) but when the textarea is larger than the viewport it causes the viewport to overflow horizontally. I tried both changing and removing `cols` both to no avail. I tried restricting the `resize` to `vertical` and that had no effect on this issue either. How can I adjust the CSS to respect `max-width`?

```
<label class="preset-box block-table font-os">
  <span class="preset-box block-table" data-spacing="mb1">Ask</span>
  <textarea aria-invalid="false" class="preset-textarea p1 pl2 pr2 font-textarea round-medium border-1px border-solid" cols="100" rows="4" data-spacing="mb1 mb0-last">Am I overflowing?</textarea>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this class:

```
block-table
```

`max-width` applies to block elements only, but `block-table` makes these table elements.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Reason for [`block-table`](https://github.com/ryanve/flow.css/tree/v0.5.0#display) there was so that clicking above the textarea on that line focuses it but not right of the edge which would be the case if all were `block`. Working demo > https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/yprdEP